# Why does LaTeX longtable start on next page?

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

I have a 3-column-longtable that spans over several pages, there's no problem with that. The thing is that there's some text before the longtable. Instead of starting right under the text, LaTeX leaves a blank space and table starts on next page. Any idea on why this may be happening? Here's some code:

```
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}

\hline

Title1 & Title2 & Title3 \\

\hline \hline

\endhead

\multicolumn{2}{c}{Continued on next page...}

\endfoot

\endlastfoot

\hline
   {Sth1} &          {Sth2} &  {Sth3}

%%% etc...
%%% etc...

\hline

\end{longtable}
```

Comment: You might need `needspace` package. The manual is very short, only 3 pages, please read it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: without a full document its impossible to say but `longtable` forces a page break if there is not room for the table head and foot and a couple of normal lines on the space left fpr the start pf the table.